# How to get object GMSPlace by longitude and lattitude and without GooglePlacePicker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I have coordinates for the place on map. Is it possible to get GMSPlace object using some method (without GooglePlacePicker) like currentPlaceWithCallback with custom longitude and lattitude?

Comment: do you want details of place using coordinates ?

Comment: I want the CMSPlace by custom coordinates

Comment: You can use GMSGeocoder to get all information about specified coordinate. To get GCMPlace i think you need placeID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with out GooglePlacePicker, you can use [CLGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder)!.